# jQuery .load() doesn't work well with Drupal 7 Views

Tags: jquery, load, view, drupal-7

I am using .load() for ajax loading my pages from the menus. It works well, however when my content is a view, it loads everything on that view. It does not take paging into account. So ie for 100 items, it will show everything and at the bottom of the page it will show paging.

As soon as I press any of the views paging links, the view behaves normally.

I have added the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#menu li a').unbind('click').click(function(){
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var toLoad = href+' #content';  
    loadContent();
    jQuery('#content').hide('slow',loadContent);
    jQuery('#load').remove();
    jQuery('#main-wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    jQuery('#load').fadeIn('normal');

    function loadContent() {
        jQuery('#content').load(toLoad,'',function(){showNewContent()});
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        jQuery('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        jQuery('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply to fix error as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#menu li a').unbind('click').click(function() {
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var toLoad = href+' #content';
        loadContent();
        jQuery('#content').hide('slow', loadContent);
        jQuery('#load').remove();
        jQuery('#main-wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        jQuery('#load').fadeIn('normal');

        function loadContent() {
            jQuery('#content').load(toLoad, '', function() {
                showNewContent();
            });
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            jQuery('#content').show('normal', hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            jQuery('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
    });
});
```

In your example you don't have additional `});` closing *tags* at the end. If the same in your site then you definetly have an error in your script. Not sure if it might help, since I didn't inspect your code if it's well written.

**[EDIT]**

But if to go further I'd recommend to write as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#menu li a').unbind('click').click(function() {
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var toLoad = href+' #content';
        loadContent();
        jQuery('#content').hide('slow', loadContent);
        jQuery('#load').remove();
        jQuery('#main-wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        jQuery('#load').fadeIn('normal');

        function loadContent() {
            jQuery('#content').load(toLoad, '', function() {
                jQuery('#content').show('normal', function() {
                    jQuery('#load').fadeOut('normal');
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

However I don't understand why you call for `jQuery('#load').remove();` if you are using this element.